# How to redirect a HTTP Request to a static File with the GET Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've a Page

```
example.com/u/_USERNAME_
```

and i want to redirect the request to

```
example.com/u/profile.php?u=_USERNAME_
```

I've tried a .htaccess (in the /u/ folder) file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ profile.php?u=$1
```

It redirects the request **BUT** the `$_GET['u']` Variable contains `profile.php`

Where's the Problem?

---

## I've solved the Problem:


The file `profile.php` was in the `/u/` Folder. So the Rule redirects to the own file and the GET Parameter get lost.
I've put the `profile.php` in the rootfolder `example.com/` and it work's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apache rewrite rules are regular expressions, and the one you wrote matches a whole string. Write a rule that matches stuff after /u/ thus so:

```
RewriteRule ^u/([^/]*)$ /u/profile.php?u=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've a .htacces file in the /u/ Folder ... and this Example didn't help